# Merging cells in crosstable in Cognos Analytics 11

Tags: crosstab, cognos-11

Help me please: i develop report in Cognos Analytics 11 with crosstable. I  need merge two cells, in one row of facts of crosstable ?
[merging like in row r2, r3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouNhc.png)

Comment: Hello,
Could you maybe take a print-screen and explain a little bit more explicit. With examples it is easier to help:)

Comment: add picture with example of crosstable with nessesary merging cells  in rows r1,r2.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far?
For example, placing a table at the top of the crosstab.  Then placing the facts side by side at the top of the crosstab within this table to control the layout?

Comment: I tried to make a nested crosstab into a regular table - this option is not suitable. In HTML format it is impossible to achieve straight boundaries of tables.